# Is "it makes following five-fold contributions" a good expression?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I saw some papers using expressions like "five-fold contributions".

What's the difference between this and "five contributions"?

Which one is better? What are the appropriate scenarios for the word "fold"?

Answer (score 4):

[*-fold* as a suffix](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-fold) implies multiplication, rather than a simple amount. You can compare the term to folding a piece of paper, although the math there is a little different (exponential rather than linear).

So, if you're only saying that someone has made five contributions, then *-fold* is not appropriate.

However, if they're making five times the contributions that they had made in previous years, then that is when you should say *fivefold* (as pointed out in the comments, note that it is generally preferred to not use a hyphen[<sup>(1)</sup>](http://www.apsstylemanual.org/oldmanual/mechanics/hyphens.htm)[<sup>(2)</sup>](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-fold#Related_terms)).

Comment: As a mathematician, I've never liked this expression. If you fold a piece of paper (over on itself) then you half the size. A second fold takes you to a quarter of the original size. A third fold takes you to an eighth of the original size. Whether increasing or decreasing, "fold" ought to refer to powers of two: either $2^k$ or $1/2^k$.

Comment: @FlybyNight: Unless you make [accordion folds](http://www.printspal.com/prodImages/_notes/Accordion.png), in which case five folds creates five additional "panels".

Comment: @FlybyNight You're right, comparing it to folding a piece of paper doesn't quite make sense - updated answer.